# Why does melt (reshape2) substitute column names by column order numbers?

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2, melt

I have a 74x74 pairwise distance matrix of SNP differences in which the first column and row correspond to the isolate's number, like this:

```
        26482RR 25638   26230   25689RR 25954
26482RR 0       8       0       6       0
25638   8       0       8       14      8
26230   0       8       0       6       0
25689RR 6       14      6       0       6
25954   0       8       0       6       0

M = structure(c(0L, 8L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 14L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 6L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("26482RR", "25638", "26230", "25689RR", 
"25954"), c("26482RR", "25638", "26230", "25689RR", "25954")))
```

I would like to convert this matrix into a table of SNP differences for each pair of isolates, like so:

```
Col      Row    SNP differences
26482RR  25638   8
26482RR  26230   0
26482RR  25689RR 6
26482RR  25954   0
25638    26230   8
25638    25689RR 14
25638    25954   8
...
```

in order to plot this data and correlate it with other matrices. I am a beginner in R so after a bit of searching I have decided to apply the following code:

```
st1076 <- read.csv("st1076.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
m1 <- as.matrix(st1076)
m1 <- m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- NA
m1_melted <- reshape2:::melt.matrix(m1, na.rm = TRUE)
colnames(m1_melted) <- c("Col","Row","SNP differences")
```

However, with this code I get in "Col" the numeration of each isolate by its order of occurrence ( 1, 2, 3, 4...) and not is respective isolate number:

```
Col     Row      SNP differences
2       X26482RR  8
3       X26482RR  0
4       X26482RR  6
```

From what I saw in other related questions, using `melt.matrix` should solve this problem but it didn't work for me.

Can anyone help me understand why this happened? Do you have any suggestions in how to overcome it?

Comment: I can't reproduce starting from your csv, but with the M that I edited in (which seems to match your display), `melt(replace(M, upper.tri(M), NA), varnames = c("Col", "Row"), value.name="SNP differences", na.rm=TRUE)` works..? I guess maybe you are melting a data.frame instead somehow.

Comment: @Frank here is my .csv file: (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AKyGaGVVl6bDgkw) , if you please could have a look. I checked the output of each step and I still can't decipher the problem, everything seems ok.

Comment: I forgot to mention before but the first part of the final output table was something like: Col: 1, Row: X, SNP differences: 26482RR, for the first 74 entries. I thought I could just delete these first entries but maybe they are related to the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You can confirm that `st1076` from the code above is not a good representation of the matrix, since `dim(st1076)` isn't 74x74. I've shown below a better way to read it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code was correct except reading from csv. Because csvs are interpreted as data frames by `read.csv`, some processing is required to get a matrix:

```
DF = read.csv("st1076.csv", sep=";", row.names=1, check.names=FALSE)
M = as.matrix(DF)

res <- reshape2::melt(replace(M, upper.tri(M), NA), 
  varnames = c("Col", "Row"), 
  value.name = "SNP differences", 
  na.rm = TRUE
)

head(res)
      Col     Row SNP differences
1 26482RR 26482RR               0
2   25638 26482RR               8
3   26230 26482RR               0
4 25689RR 26482RR               6
5   25954 26482RR               0
6   25692 26482RR               2
```

For reference, I started with this thread https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-May/237835.html and then consulted the help file `?read.csv`